# How to encrypt and decrypt sound files in Java?

Tags: java, file, audio, encryption

Is there a way to encrypt and decrypt sound files such as *.wav , *.au or *.snd files in Java ?

Edit :
I knew how to encrypt and decrypt text files, just curious if a sound file could be encrypted and decrypted, now it seems I can use the same methods.

Comment: sure, but i want to know why you want to do it ?

Comment: Maybe he's meaning "encode", but if it's the case, he needs to specify the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way. It is effectively the same as encrypting/decrypting text as the API requests or returns byte arrays.

Here is a very basic example: [Basic symmetric encryption example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/Basicsymmetricencryptionexample.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Like any other data file you can encrypt media files using standard encryption techniques.

For starters check these links....

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm

> The Tiny Encryption Algorithm (TEA) is
>   a fast, simple and robust block cipher
>   designed by David Wheeler and Roger
>   Needham. This code is released under
>   the LGPL. The algorithm is implemented
>   in a single class:

http://www.winterwell.com/software/TEA.php

http://143.53.36.235:8080/tea.htm

http://143.53.36.235:8080/TEA_java_sc.txt